# Is it possible to use a my SQL inner join query inside my ASP.NET WEB API app directly, or is it better to translate, if so how can it be done?

Tags: sql, asp.net, api

I'm working on my first (kinda) big personal project and I am stuck.  I have 4 tables, 3 of which have foreign keys linking into tbl_model_details.  All tables are listed below.

```
tbl_model_details 
tbl_model_type
tbl_model_name
tbl_model_scale
```

Ideally I want to show data through my controller with HTTP Get.  I can get Postman to to return data from my controller using `_context.tbl_model_details.ToList();`

Currently Postman is showing the id's for the other tables, but want them to show data from other columns within those tables instead of the id.

Within SQL I was able to build this query which displays the information I would like from the other tables, Is there an equivalent that I could make to run inside my controller? Or is there a way I can use this query that I have already made?

```
SELECT model_scale, model_name,  info, picture, model_type, part_number, amount_owned, modified, limited_addition, date_purchase, price_paid, upc
from tbl_model_details
join tbl_model_type
on tbl_model_details.type_id = tbl_model_type.type_id
join tbl_model_name
on tbl_model_details.name_id = tbl_model_name.name_id
join tbl_model_scale
on tbl_model_details.scale_id = tbl_model_scale.scale_id
```

Any help from you guys would be great.
Thanks

Comment: Write a query using [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Entity Frameworks LINQ Include. This will allow you to include the sub-models in the same query:

```
_context.tbl_model_details
     .Include(details => details.tbl_model_type)
     .Include(details => details.tbl_model_name)
.ToList();
```

Without knowing your relationships, DBSet and Model setups, I can say that the statement will look exactly like the one I mentioned, but this may help you get on the right track.

This will allow you to later retrieve data from the sub-models:

```
@Model.tbl_model_scale.model_scale;
```

Comment: This has really helped.  Although I am getting an Exception thrown:

`'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll but was not handled in user code: 'Lambda expression used inside Include is not valid.'

It doesn't like like the Lambda expression? Any ideas on how to fix?

Comment: I would need to see your model classes. But the lambda needs to return your sub-model. Like for example, if you had a Class model with a bunch of Students, you would do: _context.Classes.Include(class => class.Students)

Comment: I'll try and show some of that here.  Here is the TblModelType model 

```
        public int TypeId { get; set; }
        public string ModelType { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<TblModelDetails> TblModelDetails { get; set; }
```

here is my DBSet

```
  public virtual DbSet<TblModelType> TblModelType { get; set; }
```